# User doesn't exist problem in login page of django User model

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users, django-login

I have created one simple recipe website. In which i am creating a login page and register page. The register page is working fine and it saving the user credential into the User model. but when i have created the login page. it showing that username doesn't exist but the user is registered with same username and password.

I have tried all the query like using filter and get separately..but didn't get any desired result.

I expect that when user type their user name and password it redirect to recipe page. if the credentials are wrong it redirect to login page

```py
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        print(username)
        password = request.POST['password']
        # print(User.objects.filter(username=username))
               
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is None:
            messages.info(request, "user do not exit. please REGISTER")
            return redirect('/user_login/')
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/receipes/')
               
    return render(request, 'login_page.html')


def register_page(request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST['username'],
            first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    
            if User.objects.filter(username=username):
                messages.info(
                    request, "Username already exist! Please try some other username.")
                return redirect('/user_register/')
    
            user = User.objects.create(
                username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name
            )
            user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
            user.save()
            messages.success(
                request, "Your Account has been created succesfully!!"
            )
            return redirect('/user_register/')
    except:
        pass

    return render(request, 'register_page.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your project with the code you provided and I believe that I've solved your issue.

---

The TL;DR version is in your `register_page` function, remove the trailing commas after each variable like so

Before

```py
username = request.POST['username'],
first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
last_name = request.POST['last_name']
```

After

```py
username = request.POST['username']
first_name = request.POST['first_name']
last_name = request.POST['last_name']
```

If you're interested in what steps I took to figure it out, please read on because I didn't notice this at first.

---

First, I created a clean Django project and setup your code with as minimal setup as I could, to make sure that nothing else could possibly interfere with it

Second, I tried to duplicate the problem exactly as you described and had the same issue where I couldn't login to a successfully registered user.

That prompted me to check the django admin (`/admin/`) to make sure that the user was succesfully created. So I created a new superuser with `py manage.py createsuperuser` command and checked the `User` table.

Immediately I noticed some red flags, the user I tried to register through your view had this username: `('test', )`, this first name: `('tester firstname', )` and this last name: `tester lastname`. So that's told me that something was happening when the username and firstname were being processed in your view.

Finally that lead me back to check the code to your view - where I noticed the trailing commas, removed them and everything worked perfectly.

---

Comment: thanks Alexander...it was my silly mistake that i added the commas in register page this causes username to be stored as tuple

Thanks for giving me approach for solving such problems.